# How to select and insert into new table without duplicate value?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. Two tables have same fields and two table have some data. Now I want to select data in table1 and insert the the data in to table2. But I am using between, so i am confused. Please help me... Insert data in to table2 with out duplicate value.

```
INSERT INTO table2 
  (`student_id`, `studentname`, `Regno`, `class`, `date`, `session`
   , `status`, `teacher_id`) 
  SELECT * FROM table1, table2 
  WHERE table1.date <> table2.date
    BETWEEN '2011-01-01'
    AND '2011-05-19' AND table1.class = 'AAA'
```

Comment: Does table2 have a primary key? How do you define duplicate? All columns are the same or just the first ... etc?

Comment: I would expect `student_id` to be the PK (or maybe the combo (student_id + teacher_id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing a cross join on inequality which will generate an huge amount of (duplicate) rows.
Instead you should do a `LEFT JOIN` on equality and filter out the `null` rows.

I'd rewrite it to:

```
INSERT INTO table2 
  (`student_id`, `studentname`, `Regno`, `class`, `date`, `session`
   , `status`, `teacher_id`) 
SELECT t1.* FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.student_id = t2.student_id)
WHERE t1.`date` BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-05-19' 
AND t1.`class` = 'AAA'
AND t2.student_id IS NULL
```

Here `student_id` is the primary key for both t1 and t2. If the PK is (student_id + teacher_id) then the query becomes:

```
INSERT INTO table2 
  (`student_id`, `studentname`, `Regno`, `class`, `date`, `session`
   , `status`, `teacher_id`) 
SELECT t1.* FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.student_id = t2.student_id 
                        AND t1.teacher_id = t2.teacher_id)
WHERE t1.`date` BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-05-19' 
AND t1.`class` = 'AAA'
AND t2.student_id IS NULL  /*<<-- this stays the same provided student_id is  
                             <<-- defined as `NOT NULL` */
```

**Here's how it works.**
First we select all rows where `(t1.student_id = t2.student_id)`; this lines up all matching rows in t1 and t2.
Because it's a left join, rows that are in t1 but NOT in t2 will have `null` values in the t2 columns.
By only allowing rows where `t2.student_id IS NULL` we only select rows from t1 that have no matching row in t2.